# Server went to sleep mode

Tags: linux, debian, dell-poweredge, debian-squeeze

I've setup a new Dell Poweredge R410 server with debian squeeze. If the server is idle for a longer time it seems to go to sleep mode. If I ping the server, it doesn't answer for 10-20 seconds and then comes up again. In in `/var/log/messages` I can see:

```
Oct 13 12:54:56 localhost kernel: [74420.949520] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Oct 13 12:55:49 localhost kernel: [74473.200155] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
```

There is nothing configured in `/etc/acpi` that the server should go to sleep mode if there is no activity for a longer time.

Does anyone know what else can cause the issue?

Comment: Could you please post a log snippet?

Comment: I updated the question with the last log messages from /var/log/messages

Comment: Promiscuous mode is what happens when you run tools like `wireshark` to sniff all network traffic; it has nothing to do with sleeping.

Comment: Yes you're right. For further debugging I run tshark on that server. That problem appered arround that time, but no log messages to see.

Comment: Do you see something with dmesg?

Comment: No,nothing in /var/log/dmesg and /var/log/messages when it happends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the bnx2 network driver. After upgrading from version 2.0.2 to 2.0.23b the problem is solved.